# Setting up Selenium Grid on AWS Fargate

Tags: networking, amazon-ecs, selenium-grid, aws-fargate, ecs-taskdefinition

I'm trying to set up Selenium Grid on AWS fargate. I have two task definitions for the Hub and a Chrome Node. What I tried was,

- First I deploy a hub task
- manually add the private IP of the hub to the environment variable (SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST) of the node task definition.
- Deploy the node task.
  [Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdQbx.png)

In this approach the grid starts fine with the node. But I want to pass the private IP of the hub task automatically to the node task when the node task is deploying. I do not want to use a load balancer in this case due to the cost. Given that, what would be the best approach to pass the private IP of the Hub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the private IP addresses around like that, I suggest using [ECS Service Discovery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html) which will create internal DNS records for your services automatically. Then you can simply pass the domain name for the Hub task, for example `hub.internal` as your `SE_ENVENT_BUS_HOST` environment variable, and inside your internal network that address will resolve to the private IP of the Hub task.